# Python Local Variable Referenced Before Assignment Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and I'm having a bit of difficulties with using the def function.

I'm creating a program that will ask the user to select a subprogram of their choosing, which they will indicate by either putting a 1, 2, or 3.

When the user selects their program, the user will be prompted to type in their desired inputs needed for the program to solve the equation.

```
def main():
    def Home():
        print('''Please select a program.
        1: Linear Equation Solver
        2: Kirchoff's Laws Solver
        3: Voltage Divider ''')

        Program_Selection = int(input("Please select your program: "))
        if Program_Selection == 1:
            LES()
        if Program_Selection == 2:
            KCL()
        if Program_Selection == 3:
            VD()
    Home()

    def KCL():
        Voltage_Source_1 = int(input("Voltage Source 1: "))
        Voltage_Source_2 = int(input("Voltage Source 2: "))

        Resistor_1 = int(input("Resistor 1: "))
        Resistor_2 = int(input("Resistor 2: "))
        Resistor_3 = int(input("Resistor 3: "))

        Factor = ( - (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) / Resistor_3)

        Current_2 = (Voltage_Source_1 + (Factor * Voltage_Source_2)) / (((Resistor_3 + Resistor_2) * Factor) + Resistor_3) * 1000
        Current_1 = (Voltage_Source_1 - (Resistor_3 * (Current_2 / 1000))) / (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) * 1000
        Current_3 = Current_1 + Current_2

        Voltage_Resistor_1 = abs(((Current_1) / 1000) * Resistor_1)
        Voltage_Resistor_2 = abs(((Current_2) / 1000) * Resistor_2)
        Voltage_Resistor_3 = abs(((Current_3) / 1000) * Resistor_3)

        Power_Resistor_1 = abs(Current_1 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
        Power_Resistor_2 = abs(Current_2 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
        Power_Resistor_3 = abs(Current_3 * Voltage_Resistor_1)

        print("Current 1:", round(Current_1, 3), "mA.")
        print("Current 2:", round(Current_2, 3), "mA.")
        print("Current 3:", round(Current_3, 3), "mA.")

        print("Resistor 1 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_1, 3), "V.")
        print("Resistor 2 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_2, 3), "V.")
        print("Resistor 3 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_3, 3), "V.")

        print("Resistor 1 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_1, 3), "mW.")
        print("Resistor 2 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_2, 3), "mW.")
        print("Resistor 3 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_3, 3), "mW.")
    while True:
        KCL()
        if input("Would you like to repeat the program? (Yes / No): ") == "Yes":
            KCL()
        else:
            Home()

main()
```

So I understand that in order for me to call the KCL section I have to first define it, so I tried putting it before the def Home(): section; however, this would cause the KCL section to be called before the Home() section.

Once again, I'm very new to programming, so I would appreciate any help that I could get regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are intending to do is below:
the main function will be called when you run the program based on user input it will run one of the other methods. After that, at the end of each method, it will ask for user input again if it was yes it will run the method again (I believe there is no need for a while loop). I edited your code it should look something like this.

```
def main():
    print('''Please select a program.
    1: Linear Equation Solver
    2: Kirchoff's Laws Solver
    3: Voltage Divider ''')

    Program_Selection = int(input("Please select your program: "))
    if Program_Selection == 1:
        LES()
    if Program_Selection == 2:
        KCL()
    if Program_Selection == 3:
        VD()


def KCL():
    Voltage_Source_1 = int(input("Voltage Source 1: "))
    Voltage_Source_2 = int(input("Voltage Source 2: "))

    Resistor_1 = int(input("Resistor 1: "))
    Resistor_2 = int(input("Resistor 2: "))
    Resistor_3 = int(input("Resistor 3: "))

    Factor = ( - (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) / Resistor_3)

    Current_2 = (Voltage_Source_1 + (Factor * Voltage_Source_2)) / (((Resistor_3 + Resistor_2) * Factor) + Resistor_3) * 1000
    Current_1 = (Voltage_Source_1 - (Resistor_3 * (Current_2 / 1000))) / (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) * 1000
    Current_3 = Current_1 + Current_2

    Voltage_Resistor_1 = abs(((Current_1) / 1000) * Resistor_1)
    Voltage_Resistor_2 = abs(((Current_2) / 1000) * Resistor_2)
    Voltage_Resistor_3 = abs(((Current_3) / 1000) * Resistor_3)

    Power_Resistor_1 = abs(Current_1 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
    Power_Resistor_2 = abs(Current_2 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
    Power_Resistor_3 = abs(Current_3 * Voltage_Resistor_1)

    print("Current 1:", round(Current_1, 3), "mA.")
    print("Current 2:", round(Current_2, 3), "mA.")
    print("Current 3:", round(Current_3, 3), "mA.")

    print("Resistor 1 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_1, 3), "V.")
    print("Resistor 2 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_2, 3), "V.")
    print("Resistor 3 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_3, 3), "V.")

    print("Resistor 1 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_1, 3), "mW.")
    print("Resistor 2 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_2, 3), "mW.")
    print("Resistor 3 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_3, 3), "mW.")

   if input("Would you like to repeat the program? (Yes / No): ") == "Yes":
        KCL()
  else:
        main()

main()
```

P.S. Home() method is unnecessary and is extra you can remove it

Comment: No problem. If this is the solution to your program please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your **smaller** functions outside of your main function, but **above** it. Also, in python you don't have to wrap the main bulk of your program in a main function.

```
def Home():
    print('''Please select a program.
    1: Linear Equation Solver
    2: Kirchoff's Laws Solver
    3: Voltage Divider ''')

    Program_Selection = int(input("Please select your program: "))
    if Program_Selection == 1:
        LES()
    if Program_Selection == 2:
        KCL()
    if Program_Selection == 3:
        VD()
def KCL():
    Voltage_Source_1 = int(input("Voltage Source 1: "))
    Voltage_Source_2 = int(input("Voltage Source 2: "))

    Resistor_1 = int(input("Resistor 1: "))
    Resistor_2 = int(input("Resistor 2: "))
    Resistor_3 = int(input("Resistor 3: "))

    Factor = ( - (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) / Resistor_3)

    Current_2 = (Voltage_Source_1 + (Factor * Voltage_Source_2)) / (((Resistor_3 + Resistor_2) * Factor) + Resistor_3) * 1000
    Current_1 = (Voltage_Source_1 - (Resistor_3 * (Current_2 / 1000))) / (Resistor_1 + Resistor_3) * 1000
    Current_3 = Current_1 + Current_2

    Voltage_Resistor_1 = abs(((Current_1) / 1000) * Resistor_1)
    Voltage_Resistor_2 = abs(((Current_2) / 1000) * Resistor_2)
    Voltage_Resistor_3 = abs(((Current_3) / 1000) * Resistor_3)

    Power_Resistor_1 = abs(Current_1 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
    Power_Resistor_2 = abs(Current_2 * Voltage_Resistor_1)
    Power_Resistor_3 = abs(Current_3 * Voltage_Resistor_1)

    print("Current 1:", round(Current_1, 3), "mA.")
    print("Current 2:", round(Current_2, 3), "mA.")
    print("Current 3:", round(Current_3, 3), "mA.")

    print("Resistor 1 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_1, 3), "V.")
    print("Resistor 2 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_2, 3), "V.")
    print("Resistor 3 Voltage:", round(Voltage_Resistor_3, 3), "V.")

    print("Resistor 1 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_1, 3), "mW.")
    print("Resistor 2 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_2, 3), "mW.")
    print("Resistor 3 Power:", round(Power_Resistor_3, 3), "mW.")

#This is where the program starts, calling the above functions
Home()

while True:
    KCL()
    if input("Would you like to repeat the program? (Yes / No): ") == "Yes":
        KCL()
    else:
        Home()
```